# How can I display the price from this array list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, getjson

```
{"item":{"icon":"LINK REMOVED","icon_large":"LINK REMOVED","id":385,"type":"Default","typeIcon":"LINK REMOVED","name":"Shark","description":"I'd better be careful eating this.","current":{"trend":"neutral","price":"1,239"},"today":{"trend":"positive","price":"+15"},"members":"true","day30":{"trend":"positive","change":"+3.0%"},"day90":{"trend":"positive","change":"+52.0%"},"day180":{"trend":"positive","change":"+37.0%"}}}
```

I'm trying to read this json array with Javascript.

```
if(message.toLowerCase().substring(0,5) == "!item") {
    var item = message.substring(6,message.length)
    var index = 0;
    var found;
    var entry;
    for (index = 0; index < config.length; ++index) {
        entry = config[index];
        if (entry.name == item) {

        var request = require('request');
        var url = "LINK REMOVED"+ entry.id
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var gestat = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(gestat.item[6].price);
    } else {
        console.log("Got an error: ", error, ", status code: ", response.statusCode);
    }
});
        if (index > index.length) {
            client.action(channel,"This item does not exist!")
        }
        }
    }
}
```

});

I'm trying to get the price but whenever I do

```
console.log(gestat.item[6].price);
```

The console returns undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the response is the one you have given above your code

```
 console.log(getstat["item"]["current"]["price"])
```